# Hibernate generate value on non primary key with combination of field + max

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Example i have this table

table transaction

- id int (PK)
- unit varchar(10)
- journal_number

journal number is combination of unit and a sequence. so example data could be like this

```
id | unit    | journal_number
------------------------------
1  | 'unit1' | 1
2  | 'unit1' | 2
3  | 'unit2' | 1
4  | 'unit2' | 2

...
```

i how to create the journal_number automatically ?

is there any solution for this in hibernate without doing this manually ? 
like using a Generator

If i have to do this manually, for example if there is a new row for the 'unit1'. then i have to to this

```
select max(journal_number) where unit = 'unit1'
```

then asign the result to the new row

Comment: You can use composite Key.If I got it

Comment: i think maybe the composite key is the keyword, but how to generate th e journal_id automatically by sequence ?

Comment: No it is not just a keyword,There is feature in Hibernate called composite-id

Comment: after looking for a solution, it does not have to be a composite key. because composite key should be assigned by the application. i just need the journal_number generated automatically.

Comment: then it is not a keyword :) I think if you separate properties the first is generated by the application and the second by the database and combine them in a composite -id. I think it will be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't Know if I got your point.But it seems that yo want a composite Key.
if yes then there is way that you can do in your mapping file.

```
<composite-id name="MyKey" class="string">
  <key-property name="firstKey"/> 
  <key-property name="secondKey"/>
</composite-id>
```